# Width of a UIView not changing based on constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView that I am drawing and adding a subview to another UIView.

This acts as a separator so it needs to be 1px high and the width of the view that it is being added on.

This is the code I have so far:

```
 var underline = UIView()
 underline.frame = CGRectMake(0, 37, backgroundSection.bounds.size.width, 1)
 underline.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
 backgroundSection.addSubview(underline)
```

This doesn't draw the UIView's width to be the same width as backgroundSection. This draws it as the same width as how backgroundSection looks on the IB before constraints have resized the view.

I could set backgroundSection's clipToBounds to true but I have a shadow on backgroundSection that would be removed if it were to be set to true.

How can I fix this.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using frame setting when you are using constraints. Auto Layout will do all of the frame setting for you.

Instead, you need to add constraints to your view:

```
var underline = UIView()
backgroundSection.addSubview(underline)

// These two lines will add horizontal and vertical constraints pinning the underline view to backgroundSection's edges
backgroundSection.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": underline]))
backgroundSection.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view": underline]))
```